# ios - Custom delegate method is not triggered

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, uitabbarcontroller, protocols

I have added a round button in TabBarController using the following code

```
import UIKit

protocol AddButtonProtocol: class {
   func addButtonIsClicked()
}

 class MainTabBar: UITabBar {

     open var buttonDelegate: AddButtonProtocol?
    private var middleButton = UIButton()

    override open func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        setupMiddleButton()
    }

    override open func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        if self.isHidden {
            return super.hitTest(point, with: event)
        }

        let from = point
        let to = middleButton.center

        return sqrt((from.x - to.x) * (from.x - to.x) + (from.y - to.y) * (from.y - to.y)) <= 39 ? middleButton : super.hitTest(point, with: event)
    }

    func setupMiddleButton() {
        middleButton.frame.size = CGSize(width: 70, height: 70)
        middleButton.backgroundColor = .blue
        middleButton.layer.cornerRadius = 35
        middleButton.layer.masksToBounds = true
        middleButton.center = CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2, y: 0)
        middleButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(test), for: .touchUpInside)
        addSubview(middleButton)
    }

    @objc func test() {
        print("add button is clicked")
        buttonDelegate?.addButtonIsClicked()

    }
}
```

It looks like this.

[image]

Now whenever I click that button, the method in `HomeScreenVCViewController` should be triggered. So I have implemented the protocol and delegates like this.

```
import UIKit

class HomeScreenVCViewController: UIViewController {
    var addButtonDelegate: MainTabBar!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addButtonDelegate?.buttonDelegate = self
    }

}

extension HomeScreenVCViewController: AddButtonProtocol {
    func addButtonIsClicked() {
        print("protocol is working") // Not getting called
    }
}
```

But its not working at all, addButtonIsClicked method is not getting triggered when I tap that round button. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: it seems that `addButtonDelegate` is `nil`.

Comment: Yes it is nil..

Comment: check edited answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   (tabBarController.tabBar as? MainTabBar)?.buttonDelegate = self
}
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Delegate is not getting called b'coz `addButtonDelegate` is nil. You do not initialise `addButtonDelegate` so the `addButtonDelegate` object is `nil`

**Solution**

Either you need to make `addButtonDelegate` as an `@IBOutlet` or you need to initialise it in `viewDidLoad:` method.

Then only delegate will be called.

**Example 1**

```
@IBOutlet weak var addButtonDelegate: MainTabBar!
```

and in viewDidLoad

```
addButtonDelegate.buttonDelegate = self
```

**Example 2**

Create property like

```
var addButtonDelegate: MainTabBar?
```

in viewDidLoad initialise `addButtonDelegate`.

```
addButtonDelegate = MainTabBar() //or any other initialiser
addButtonDelegate?.buttonDelegate = self
```

Comment: Already tried your example 2. that didn't work. Now example 1 also didn't work either bro.

Comment: in ex 1, have you connected iboutlet to your MainTabBar in storyboard or xib?

Answer (score 1):

You did not initialize `MainTabBar` in `HomeScreenVCViewController`. Thats why `addButtonDelegate` is `nil`

```
var addButtonDelegate: MainTabBar = MainTabBar()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addButtonDelegate?.buttonDelegate = self
    }
```

Comment: Sadly tried this already bro. It didn't work either. I'm sorry I should have mentioned all my tries in the post.

Comment: Did you debugged where `addButtonDelegate` is becoming nil?

Comment: The protocol and delegate object is well defined in MainTabBar, why it should be nil when trying to initialise that delegate object in HomeScreenVCViewController. I really couldn't find why it is nil.